# colorbox cannot passing POST data with $(this) selector

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, this, colorbox

I have searched any thread here and still not found for my spesific problem. I have a list of data and every row have editBtn that assign to be as colorbox. My code in below :

```
$('.editBtn').colorbox({
  href: '<?=site_url('jkitem/editjkitem')?>',
  iframe: false,
  title: 'Change Item',
  transition: 'elastic', 
  speed: 200, 
  opacity: 0.6,
  fadeOut: 300,
  overlayClose: false,
  data: { edited_jkitem : $(this).attr('value')},
  onClosed: function(){
       location.reload();
  }
 });
```

As seen above, I still cannot pass $(this).attr('value') to my controller. Is there any reason for this problem?

Comment: Yes, `this` isn't what you think it is, resulting in `$(this).attr('value')` not getting what you intend for it to. `this` is not the current `.editBtn`.

Comment: But why when I try to pass by 'GET' with data: function(){ return 'edited_jkitem='+$(this).attr('value') } it can return correct result?  Why cannot implemented too by 'POST' method? Is there any solution for getting current value of .editBtn by post?

Comment: You are misdiagnosing the problem. GET and POST have nothing to do with this. Note, the code you posted in your comment uses a function for data, not an object. That is a completely different scenario where `this` **would** be what you think it is.

Comment: `var a = {foo: "bar"};` and `var a = function() { return {foo: "bar"}; }` are not the same.

Comment: So, there is no solution for getting value in current .editBtn via POST?

Comment: Yes, there is. do it the same way you did it for GET, returning an object rather than a string.

Answer (score 1):

This is based on comments:

The reason it works for your GET and not POST is because you're doing them two very different ways. If you do your POST the same way you do GET, it will work.

```
data: function(){ 
    return { edited_jkitem : $(this).attr('value') }
}
```